# Placing value retrieve at correct position and order irrespective of order

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am receiving value in random fashion from query
and i want to bind table in the same order as written in code  so that table 
formed correctly
but receiving value in different order from query so order value is misplaced in generated table .
Receiving value in prop_name & tdc_property column as
below

- prop_name---- tdc_property
- 4tolMax-----------      2
- 2sizeMax --------       1
- 3tolMin-----------        3
- 1sizMin-----------         4

reading data through

```
OracleDataReader ReadData = objFetchCmd.ExecuteReader();



while (ReadData.Read())
{    
 if (prop_name == "1sizMin")
 {     
  lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-First-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
  StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
if (prop_name == "2sizeMax")
 {
  lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
if (prop_name == "3tolMin")
{
lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
 }
if (prop_name == "4tolMax")
{
 lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='bo-rig-top'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td></tr>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
```

code is written in such a way that it read row wise value actually it should read first 1sizMin then 2sizeMax..so on but in output from query it is receiving 4tolMax then 2sizeMAx...so if value is read in this fashion then value will be misplaced from it's exact position how to manage in code so that correct value should be placed at correct position.
any idea would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can...

- rewrite your query so that the rows are in the desired order (see plsql ORDER BY clause)
- read all rows into a datastructure and sort that in memory before creating your output (I'd suggest a `System.Data.DataTable` here)
- you can also split your query up into 4 like Tofik suggests, but i think 'the less queries the better' in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

Change the query to first read only 1sizMin, then 2sizeMax etc... Add those categories one by one.

example:

```
//set query

    while (ReadData.Read())
    {                
      lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-First-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
      StdSize = StdSize + 1;          
}
//set query
    while (ReadData.Read())
        {              
          lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
         StdSize = StdSize + 1;              
    }
//set query
    while (ReadData.Read())
        {              
        lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
         StdSize = StdSize + 1;             
    }
//set query
    while (ReadData.Read())
        {              
         lblStdSize_Toler.Text = lblStdSize_Toler.Text + "<td class='bo-rig-top'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td></tr>";
         StdSize = StdSize + 1;              
    }
```

Tell me if it works for you.

----EDIT----

Or. Build 4 different strings, then get them together and insert it into lblStdSize_Toler.Text. Like:

```
while (ReadData.Read())
{    
 if (prop_name == "1sizMin")
 {     
  1sizMinString = 1sizMinString + "<td class='td-First-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
  StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
if (prop_name == "2sizeMax")
 {
  2sizeMaxString = 2sizeMaxString  + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
if (prop_name == "3tolMin")
{
3tolMinString = 3tolMinString  + "<td class='td-sec-col-value'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
 }
if (prop_name == "4tolMax")
{
 4tolMaxString = 4tolMaxString  + "<td class='bo-rig-top'><center>" + tdc_property + "</center></td></tr>";
 StdSize = StdSize + 1;
  }
 lblStdSize_Toler.Text=1sizMinString +2sizeMaxString +3tolMinString +4tolMaxString ;
```

Just the tip. Use:

```
StdSize++;
```

instead of

```
StdSize = StdSize + 1;
```

for cleaner code.

Comment: I think you should just use ORDER BY in query as @DarkSquirrel42 stated

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column in database named 'SortOrder' with Number as data type and add at the time of executing the query you can sort your data like this:

```
select * from yourTable order by SortOrder.
```